# Running PyTest through Travis CI encounters TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, pytest, travis-ci

I'm using Travis CI to run PyTest on my first open source project (https://travis-ci.com/github/tamir-dingjan/memly/jobs/459491449). I noticed yesterday that PyTest cannot run properly in recent runs, despite working fine in the past.

This is the error, from the Travis CI log:

```
pytest -v --cov=memly memly/tests/

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test/bin/pytest", line 11, in <module>

    sys.exit(main())

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

The command "pytest -v --cov=memly memly/tests/" exited with 1.
```

I want to understand how I can fix this. Do I need to specify a different/older version of PyTest to avoid a recent update?